# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RCurl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):

Tags: r, error-handling, rcurl

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RCurl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-RCurl/00new/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-RCurl/00new/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: '@rpath/libcurl.4.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-RCurl/00new/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so'
  Reason: tried: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libcurl.4.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1+12/Contents/Home/lib/server/libcurl.4.dylib' (no such file)
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RCurl’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RCurl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
```

The downloaded source packages are in

```
‘/private/var/folders/9m/2mfljv2d3bbc0gdnxk892dzm0000gn/T/RtmpiKY9tT/downloaded_packages’
```

I found some solutions on Linux. On macOS,  I don't see any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. For me the issue was the conflicting `curl-config` installed system-wide on mac and the `curl-config` in my base conda environment that was getting auto-activated.

Steps that worked for me.

- Run `conda deactivate` to deactivate the conda environment
- Start `R`
- Run the package installation again (`install.packages("RCurl")`).